# Javascript: compare values in protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I want to compare two values (VALUE) that are placed within text in two html elements with protractor:

```
<p>
    VALUE and other
</p>
...
<p>
    Message about stuff containing VALUE  and usefull information.
</p>
```

I have no problem to acces the texts, but as you can see, the strings containing my value have to be stripped in a custom way.

The result of `.getInnerHtml()` which I use to get the texts always return **promises** no strings. But how I can not get a string out of it to modify it to compare it with another modified string?

Comment: Was you issue solved? I am facing same issue and waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a generic getElementText function and then use Expect to compare two texts in your page:

```
  getElementText = function(elementLocator) { 
  return elementLocator.getText().then(function(text) { 
     return function() { 
     return text;
   }; 
  }); 
};

 var text1 = getElementText(element(by.id('your text1 id'))); 
 // do some actions on text1
 var text2 = getElementText(element(by.id('your text2 id')));

 expect(text1).toEqual(text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to resolve the promises as an array of strings, use a regular expression to capture the value from the strings, and compare:

```
Promise.all([
    element1.getInnerHtml(),
    element2.getInnerHtml()
]).then(function(results) {
    var getValueFromString = function(inputString) {
        return /(\d+)/.exec(inputString)[1];
    };
    var value1 = getValueFromString(results[0]);
    var value2 = getValueFromString(results[1]);
    expect(value1).toBe(value2);
});
```